Close popover with HTML & popover api only?
I'm working with the new HTML Popover API and I was wondering if there was an HTML solution to closing the popover when clicking on one of the anchor elements inside the popover?


<button popovertarget="mypopover">Toggle popover</button>

<div id="mypopover" popover>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>



I'm looking for an HTML solution that allows me to close the popover specifically when clicking on an anchor element inside the popover, without affecting the functionality of the anchor element itself.
There is a javascript method available HTMLElement.togglePopover() but still isn't great for accessibility (utilizing on onclick with an anchor element).
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
the following did not work
<a href="#" popoverhide>Home</a>


what makes you think that a click event on an anchor influences accessibility negatively?

we have an html solution for button / input element, but not for anchor element.. Ref - popovertargetaction="hide"

in that link that is documentation to a specific framework is nothing that states that normal JS and HTML have a negative influence if you add a click event to an anchor.

@tacoshy sorry that was the wrong link. Again, I'm looking for an HTML solution so an onclick handler isn't my goal. But here is why I avoid onclick handlers on anchor elements:

Keyboard Inaccessibility: Breaks expected Enter key behavior for link activation.
Screen Reader Confusion: Disrupts how screen readers identify and announce links.
Right-Click Issues:  Can interfere with standard browser context menu options.


thats why I said click not onclick. Use an addEventListener. Screen readers do not announce those. Besides that, Screen readers do not need to know that a click will hide the menu as they jump to the linked element anyways
